Sci-fi book I read in the 80s about a guy on the run who was given a rifle that had flechettes
I am looking for a title of a book I read in the 80s as a kid. It was a sci-fi novel where the protagonist was on the run. I remember he was given a rifle that had flechettes and they were fighting some sort of war. I believe he had some sort of information and was escaping/on the run. They also had a virtual reality program that they could use.
That's really all I remember. It had to be released before 1990 for sure.

You don't think this might be one of the shadowrun books?

Note that flechette weapons weren't especially common; ISTR Sten used one in one of the series, but I can't recall which.  There were a few other cases, but mostly I remember flechette ammo from Twilight 2000 and The Hitcher.

My first instinct was Endymion by Dan Simmons, where Raul et al encounter a large floating platform on one of the worlds they visit while hiding from the Pax and uses a flechette rifle, but it looks like it was published in 1996?

Count Zero or something else by Gibson?

The Dorsai books (Child Cycle) involves flechette weapons and protagonists on the run.  Certainly would fit your time window.

Man on the run + “flechettes” made me think of The Long Run by Daniel Keyes Moran, but I don’t think there were flechette rifles in that - there were weapons that fire tons of slivers that contain drugs. There was a war in the series that started in the next book (The Last Dancer) but not in the one with Trent on the run. Gibson had flechettes (as mentioned) but no wars.

I will check out all these suggestions. I really appreciate this group!

In the Hammers Slammers universe, flechette weapons are used as an alternative to powerguns by some armies.  Definitely in a war in all the stories/books, but can't remember a plot in which a single person is on the run and there is VR.

It's entering into the 90s, but might you have read one of the Shadowrun novels? The series, as with the tabletop game, is about people operating from the shadows of society, often because there is something that they are running from. One of the first books released, Never Deal With a Dragon, had the title character being pursued by his company's security after helping a shadowrunning team (he discovered that they were being tricked into releasing a deadly virus, they insisted that he come with them, and he's forced to shoot a security guard in self defense). Flechette weapons are a common sight in the setting, used to cause more damage against non-armored targets, and I'm pretty sure that it came up specifically in the first book. Another aspect of the setting is the Matrix and decking, which is basically virtual reality hacking.

The year is 2050. The power of magic and the creatures it brings have returned to the earth, and many of the ancient races have re-emerged. Elves, Orks, Mages and lethal Dragons find a home in a world where technology and human flesh have melded into deadly urban predators. And the multinational mega-corporations hoard the only thing of real value - information.
For Sam Verner, living in the womb of the Renraku conglomerate was easy, until his sister disappeared and the facade of the corporate reality began to disintegrate. Now Sam wants out, but to "extract" himself, he has to slide like a whisper through the deadly shadows the corporations cast, through a world where his first wrong move may be his last... the world of Shadowrun.

Not matching is that there's no overt war, mainly people trying to survive, the conflicts between megacorporations, and the machinations of a dragon.
